# Installing Windows from USB: "Disk Boot Failure, Insert System Disk"

Tags: bios, windows-8, usb-boot

I used Microsoft's DVD to USB Tool in order to put the Windows 8 installation disc onto an USB stick. It worked on one computer, while on another one it didn't work.

When changing the boot order, the computer rather boots normally. When changing it to *only* boot from USB, it says something similar to `Disk Boot Failure, Insert System Disk`.

I tested this USB stick on the first machine where it worked and it still is working, so the problem must be on the machine (the one where it's not working).

**Question:** Is there a BIOS setting I have to make (despite of the boot order) in order to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

The only option I didn't even think to check was the option that needed to be changed (as always). The issue wasn't changing the boot sequence order by adding USB but rather adjusting the "Hard drive" option in the boot sequence to check USB first and then hard drive. Apparently, The flash will read as an actual hard drive.

Comment: It's a bit counterintuitive that the flash disk settings are in hard drive section and not in removable disk section. You saved my day, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to bring up the Quickboot menu and selecting the USB device from there. It is usually an F-key (i.e., F12) that you'd hit during the same time that you can hit the key to get into the BIOS.

[image: Boot menu]

Comment: I can only press DEL in order to enter BIOS.

Comment: @DevilsChild it doesn't say that the menu exists on my machine either, but hitting F8 brings up the menu in the picture. I believe it's F12 on Dells.

Answer (score 1):

In some case, you need to **Enable** `External Device boot` or sometimes called `USB Boot` from `BIOS Settings` in order to see `Flash Drive` in option.

Check your computer specific BIOS Settings for more precise `USB Settings`, `External Device Boot` & `BOOT ORDER` related information.

Try other `Boot Devices` listed in `Boot Menu`, sometimes it is known as `Mass Storage` or comes under `Hard Drive`!

PS: Don't forget to `Save Changes and Exit.` in `BIOS`! [Similar Q/A at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/183732/86467)

Comment: The computer is about 5 years old. The mainboard is the `ASUS M2N-SLI Deluxe` and the only bootable item shown up matching an USB stick is called "Removable". So I guess "Removable" is not an USB stick in this manner?

Comment: Glad that problem is solved just by changing Boot Order! I was about to suggest you to look for `ASUS M2N-SLI Deluxe > BIOS > Advanced > USB Configuration` for further trial-n-errors!

Answer (score 0):

Some motherboards (especially old ones) **cannot** boot from USB, to find out whether it's a bad .iso or similar you could try putting something like an ubuntu livecd on your usb with [UNetbootin](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/unetbootin/UNetbootin/581/unetbootin-linux-581?r=http%3A%2F%2Funetbootin.sourceforge.net%2F&ts=1351367766&use_mirror=garr) as this program never made unbootable USB for me. If that doesn't work it's definitely a motherboard problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on a MSI GE40 laptop and resolved it by switching "Boot Mode" from "Legacy" to "UEFI".